could not find driver filament external API
Good day all,
i am newbie in filament and i follow the tutorial   but there is an error show me.
could not find driver 

create table "products" ("id" integer primary key autoincrement not null, "title" varchar, "description" varchar, "category" varchar, "price" float, "rating" float, "brand" varchar, "thumbnail" varchar)

please can advice me to solve this issue

To run the tutorial you have to follow the steps below :

Use the Database as SQLite
Install pdo_sqlite module into the PHP environment (XAMMP, MAMP, Vagrant)
Go to .env file and change the line of DB_DATABASE=/srv/app/filariba.sqlite

Then run the project
